# Plugged in but discharging, why?

Tags: power

My Laptop says DC 19V, 2.37A, 45W
The charger I am using is 19V,3.42A,65W

What is the reason my laptop charging status says plugged in but discharging?
I am using ASUS UX305CA model, is there something wrong with overloading with higher power? HELP!

Comment: i owned a Dell laptop that had a hotkey for turning the charging circuit on and off .... maybe yours does also and you accidentally triggered it

Comment: If the battery is charged, that's normal.  The laptop won't try to recharge the battery until it drops below a threshold.  It will use battery power even if plugged in until the battery drops below the charging threshold.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when a laptop uses proprietary high-frequency communication protocol over supply wires to identify the native AC-DC adapter, so the laptop knows the exact power it can extract out of it. If laptop fails to get right signature, it will use most conservative path and might refuse to charge.

Comment: Very good point. Hadn't considered the fact that some manufacturers build in unnecessary proprietary equipment requirements. That's probably it.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is nothing wrong (under most conditions) with using a power supply that has an amp/watt rating higher than required.

As long as you have the correct voltage, polarity, and at least as much current available as the circuit needs, the circuit will work and only draw as much power as it needs.

You may want to check the output voltage with a meter to make sure your adapter is working properly. Assuming it is, the issue could be a problem with the laptop or some software configuration that prevents it from charging under certain conditions. (My Sony laptop will only actually charge once the battery drops below around 90%.)